# Is there a plugin to exclude some JavaScripts from specific page / post

Tags: javascript, wordpress

In [heptasarim.com](http://www.heptasarim.com) there are several JavaScript files and plugin loading on every page and post. Naturally this situtation effects loading speed of pages and posts. I want to exlude some useless js and css files on header from specific post or page.

Is there a plugin that will work fine for this or must I write some code ?

Comment: You could use a script loader such as Labjs or requirejs or similar and write some simple magic in `functions.php`

Comment: Thank you elclanrs, really isn't there a plugin to modify js and css. Interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a plugin, just wrap them in php conditional statements.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags

Doing so you can set the files and scripts to appear only on certain pages, posts, categories, tags, etc etc

Comment: Perfect. Thanks CoreyRS. Actually I knew that page and statements but I wanted to be sure. I am starting coding :)

Comment: I have a page named scripts_init.php. Js files is enqueued in that file. There are so lines about inserting js files.
function themeton_clean_theme_scripts_print() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-twitter');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-prettyphoto');
    wp_enqueue_script('theme-jquery-ui-custom');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-validator');

Comment: Now how can I edit this lines. I think this inserting isn't true:
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-twitter');
if(is_front_page()) { /jquery.tweet.js };

Comment: I got it OK.
if(is_front_page()) {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-twitter');}